# Clearing memory when training Machine Learning models with Tensorflow 1.15 on GPU

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I am training a pretty intensive ML model using a GPU and what will often happen that if I start training the model, then let it train for a couple of epochs and notice that my changes have not made a significant difference in the loss/accuracy, I will make edits, re-initialize the model and re-start training from epoch 0. In this case, I often get OOM errors.

My guess is that despite me overriding all the model variables something is still taking up space in-memory.

Is there a way to clear the memory of the GPU in Tensorflow 1.15 so that I don't have to keep restarting the kernel each time I want to start training from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what GPUs you're using. I'm assuming you're using NVIDIA, but even then depending on the exact GPU there are three ways to do this-

1. `nvidia-smi -r` works on TESLA and other modern variants.
2. `nvidia-smi --gpu-reset` works on a variety of older GPUs.
3. Rebooting is the only options for the rest, unfortunately.

Comment: I do have a TESLA GPU, sorry for not mentioning that. When I run it I get a message that I do not have sufficient permissions. I imagine I can run sudo nvidia-smi -r, but could give a bit more info on what that command will do?

Comment: It tells the GPU to reset itself, which includes cycling the ECC Ram.

Comment: Gotcha. I tried running it and since I am doing this from inside IPython I get a message saying that "1 device is currently being used by one or more other processes, please kill all processes using this device...". Is there a way around that from inside an IPython shell. Perhaps Tensorflow has some API for this?

Comment: If you run `nvidia-smi` with no flags it should show you a list of processes that are running and using the GPU. You can then kill the process with normal `kill` commands.